# How to use mybatis mapper as common repository for different modules

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I want to create a common module, which i will use in different modules.
Most of modules are using mybatis, and some modules are using Spring Data with Hibernate.

I have an idea to create a common interface and default implementation for Mybatis.

So im trying to create common interface

```
public interface ScheduledTaskRepository {

    List<ScheduledTask> getTasksByStateAndType( ScheduledTaskState state, ScheduledTaskType type, int maxRunCount );

    void create( ScheduledTask task );

    void update( ScheduledTask task );

    List<ScheduledTask> getTasksForReset( ScheduledTaskState state, ScheduledTaskType type, int runCount );

    void resetTask( long id );

    ScheduledTask get( long id );

}
```

and it's mybatis implementation

```
@Mapper
@ConditionalOnBean(MybatisAutoConfiguration.class)
public interface MybatisScheduledTaskRepository extends ScheduledTaskRepository {

    @Override
    @Select("SELECT * FROM scheduled_tasks WHERE state = #{state} AND type = #{type} AND run_count < #{maxRunCount}")
    List<ScheduledTask> getTasksByStateAndType( @Param("state") ScheduledTaskState state,
                                                @Param("type") ScheduledTaskType type,
                                                @Param("maxRunCount") int maxRunCount );

    @Override
    @Insert("INSERT INTO scheduled_tasks (creation_time, last_run, state, run_count, type, obj_id) " +
        "VALUES (#{creationTime}, #{lastRun}, #{state}, #{runCount}, #{type}, #{objId})")
    void create( ScheduledTask task );

    @Override
    @Update("UPDATE scheduled_tasks SET creation_time = #{creationTime}, last_run = #{lastRun}, state = #{state}, " +
        "run_count = #{runCount}, type = #{type}, obj_id = #{objId} WHERE id = #{id}")
    void update( ScheduledTask task );

    @Override
    @Select("SELECT * FROM scheduled_tasks WHERE state = #{state} AND type = #{type} AND run_count >= #{runCount}")
    List<ScheduledTask> getTasksForReset( @Param("state") ScheduledTaskState state,
                                          @Param("type") ScheduledTaskType type,
                                          @Param("runCount") int runCount );

    @Override
    @Update("UPDATE scheduled_tasks SET run_count = 0 where id = #{id}")
    void resetTask( @Param("id") long id );

    @Override
    @Select("SELECT * FROM scheduled_tasks WHERE od = #{id}")
    ScheduledTask get( @Param("id") long id );
}
```

Then i create service in the common module for working with mapper

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ScheduledTaskService {

    private final ScheduledTaskRepository scheduledTaskRepository;

    public void create( ScheduledTask scheduledTask ) {
        scheduledTaskRepository.create( scheduledTask );
    }

    public void create( ScheduledTaskType scheduledTaskType, Long objId ) {
        ScheduledTask scheduledTask = new ScheduledTask();
        scheduledTask.setCreationTime( LocalDateTime.now() )
            .setState( ScheduledTaskState.AWAIT )
            .setType( scheduledTaskType )
            .setObjId( objId )
            .setRunCount( 0 );
        scheduledTaskRepository.create( scheduledTask );
    }

    public void resetTasksTryCount( ScheduledTaskType type, int runCount ) {
        List<ScheduledTask> tasksToReset = scheduledTaskRepository.getTasksForReset( ScheduledTaskState.AWAIT, type, runCount );
        tasksToReset.forEach( task -> {
            task.setRunCount( 0 );
            update( task );
        } );
    }

    public void resetTaskTryCount( long id ) {
        scheduledTaskRepository.resetTask( id );
    }

    public void update( ScheduledTask scheduledTask ) {
        scheduledTaskRepository.update( scheduledTask );
    }

    public List<ScheduledTask> getTasksByStateAndType( ScheduledTaskState state, ScheduledTaskType type, int maxRunCount ) {
        return scheduledTaskRepository.getTasksByStateAndType( state, type, maxRunCount );
    }

    public ScheduledTask get( long id ) {
        return scheduledTaskRepository.get( id );
    }
```

This is my build.gradle of common module

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':common-modules:general')

    compileOnly 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.1.3'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    api "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:${swagger_version}"

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

}
```

spring.factories in common module

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
  ru.test.app.common.scheduling.CommonScheduling
```

And the problem is that when i include common module as dependency of another module and trying to run test, where im calling service, i get the exception

```
    Invalid bound statement (not found): ru.test.app.common.scheduling.repository.ScheduledTaskRepository.getTasksByStateAndType
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): ru.test.app.common.scheduling.repository.ScheduledTaskRepository.getTasksByStateAndType
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$SqlCommand.<init>(MapperMethod.java:235)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.<init>(MapperMethod.java:53)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.lambda$cachedMapperMethod$0(MapperProxy.java:98)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.cachedMapperMethod(MapperProxy.java:97)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:92)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy193.getTasksByStateAndType(Unknown Source)
    at ru.test.app.common.scheduling.service.ScheduledTaskService.getTasksByStateAndType(ScheduledTaskService.java:50)
    at ru.test.app.common.scheduling.processor.AbstractTaskProcessor.getPendingTasks(AbstractTaskProcessor.java:28)
    at ru.test.app.egron.sheduling.processor.SendStatusUpdateEventProcessor.prepareTasks(SendStatusUpdateEventProcessor.java:27)
    at ru.test.app.common.scheduling.processor.AbstractListTaskProcessor.process(AbstractListTaskProcessor.java:25)
    at ru.test.app.egron.scheduling.SendMortgageStatusUpdateEventProcessorTest.testProcess(SendMortgageStatusUpdateEventProcessorTest.java:32)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During debugging i have found, that into `ScheduledTaskService` field `scheduledTaskRepository` injecting `org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy` with mapperInterface `ru.test.app.common.scheduling.repository.ScheduledTaskRepository`

So, problem was solved by moving child interface that annotated with `@Mapper` to the another package (ru.test.app.common.scheduling.repository.impl), and by adding annotation `@MapperScan("ru.test.app.common.scheduling.repository.impl")`
to Application.class.